# How to copy a project from one TFS account to another?

Tags: tfs

I have a project under the TFS account provided by my company. I want to copy the project under my personal TFS account so that I can play with it and do some changes for learning.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on what you want to do.

Executing a complete migration can be hard. You need specialized tooling like the [TFS Integration Tools](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

Probably the easiest solution is to do a snapshot migration of your source code (where you lose all history). Migrating work items can be done by using Excel and some copy/paste work.

Currently there are no out of the box options for migrating build definitions (although the build workflows are part of source control), test results and release templates.

If possible, just migrate your source code and the work items if you have them.

### UPDATE

If you only want to migrate source code without history you can do this by taking a copy of the source code from TFS and then checking it into your new TFS server. Have a look at [Understanding TFS migrations from on-premises to Visual Studio Online – Part 2: Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2015/02/03/understanding-tfs-migrations-from-on-premise-to-visual-studio-online-part-2-walkthrough.aspx) for a walkthrough created by the ALM Rangers to help you with this.

Comment: I just want to migrate the source code and to be able to run the app locally.